# no activity found to handle intene (act=Main)

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my log cat error

> 02-05 16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
>   02-05 16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=MAIN } 02-05 16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
>   02-05 16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
>   02-05 16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827) 02-05
>   16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933) 02-05
>   16:31:12.441: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at
>   sp.com.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:26) 02-05 16:31:21.781:
>   I/Process(696): Sending signal. PID: 696 SIG: 9

this is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sp.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SPLASH"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Confirm1" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Malay" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Stall" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Western" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Confirm2" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Client" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Chinese" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MAIN" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
make i know why i cant run the program?
```

Comment: Will you provide your java file as well? Your program should work as @FoamyGuy said.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you edited your manifest, and it no longer has any activies that have action.MAIN in their intent filter.

Change this:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

to this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

and it should work properly.